# Rows to Customized XML

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have Employee table with me.
I want to convert each row of that table into XML

```
select d = 
     (select a.* for xml path('Root'), type, elements absent)
from MyEmployees a
```

Following is the result

Row 1:

```
<Root>
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <FirstName>Ken</FirstName>
    <LastName>Sánchez</LastName>
    <Title>Chief Executive Officer</Title>
    <DeptID>16</DeptID>
</Root>
```

Row 2:

```
<Root>
    <EmployeeID>16</EmployeeID>
    <FirstName>David</FirstName>
    <LastName>Bradley</LastName>
    <Title>Marketing Manager</Title>
    <DeptID>4</DeptID>
    <ManagerID>273</ManagerID>
</Root>
```

---

Result should in similar to below format

```
<Root>
    <Item Name="FirstName" type="String">Ken</Item>
    <Item Name="LastName" type="String">Sánchez</Item>
</Root>
```

Note: type  should be Int for DeptId.

How should I write the SQL query ?

I have tried below query:

```
SELECT EmployeeID
      ,( SELECT firstname AS '@FirstName',lastname AS '@LastName' FROM MyEmployees AS b WHERE a.EmployeeID= b.EmployeeID FOR XML PATH('Employee') ) AS RowXML
FROM  MyEmployees AS a
```

Getting result as:

```
1   <Employee FirstName="Ken" LastName="Sánchez"/>
```

---

Comment: So what you have tried for this till now?

Comment: Tried below query:
SELECT EmployeeID
      ,( SELECT firstname AS '@FirstName',lastname AS '@LastName' FROM MyEmployees AS b WHERE a.EmployeeID= b.EmployeeID FOR XML PATH('Employee') ) AS RowXML
FROM  MyEmployees AS a
--------------
Got the below results
<Employee FirstName="Ken" LastName="Sánchez"/>

Comment: Don't add your code in comment.. Edit the question instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select (
       select T.Name as [@Name],
              T.Type as [@type],
              T.Value as [*]
       from (values
              ('EmployeeID', 'Int',    cast(E.EmployeeID as varchar(10))),
              ('FirstName',  'String', E.FirstName),
              ('LastName',   'String', E.LastName),
              ('Title',      'String', E.Title),
              ('DeptID',     'Int',    cast(E.DeptID as varchar(10)))
            ) as T(Name, Type, Value)
       for xml path('Item'), root('Root'), type
       ) 
from MyEmployees as E
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee57ee/2)